# Python requests PUT dictionary

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I am using python 3 to PUT some data via API on a website.
I need to upload the data with following format:

```
data = {'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S1': {'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'name': 'TEST2'}, 'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S2': {'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'name': 'TEST'}}
```

I have a CSV file where I have all the mac addresses, IPs and names I want to upload.
The CSV looks like this:

```
MAC, IP, NAME
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S1, 1.1.1.1, TEST
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S2, 2.2.2.2, TEST2
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S3, 3.3.3.3, TEST3
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S4, 4.4.4.4, TEST4
```

How can I use this data from the CSV to upload them like a dictionary(see sample) to the website?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
import csv
data = {}
with open("input.csv") as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=",")
    for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
      if idx > 0:
        data[row[0]] = {'ip': row[1],'name':row[2]}
print(data)
```

input.csv

```
MAC, IP, NAME
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S1, 1.1.1.1, TEST
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S2, 2.2.2.2, TEST2
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S3, 3.3.3.3, TEST3
MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S4, 4.4.4.4, TEST4
```

output

```
{'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S1': {'ip': ' 1.1.1.1', 'name': ' TEST'}, 'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S2': {'ip': ' 2.2.2.2', 'name': ' TEST2'}, 'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S3': {'ip': ' 3.3.3.3', 'name': ' TEST3'}, 'MA:C0:AD:DR:ES:S4': {'ip': ' 4.4.4.4', 'name': ' TEST4'}}
```

Comment: Wow dude! I went for so long without even knowing 'enumerate' in Python! You just openend a new world for me :). Thnx for your answer! It works like a charm.